# How to read string output from PL/SQL using java?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure for SQl and will return a string as output, as show below

```
create PROCEDURE "PRATIK"."PRC_test3" (IN param1 INT,
     param2 NVARCHAR(15),
     OUT outParam1 VARCHAR (2000)) 
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    --DEFAULT SCHEMA <default_schema_name>
    --READS SQL DATA AS 
    AS

BEGIN 
----------- ### Exception Handler ### ------------------------
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN 
outParam1 := 'SQL Exception occured. Error Code is: ' || ::SQL_ERROR_CODE || ' Error message is: ' || ::SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE;

END;

outparam1 := ' Param2: ' || :param2 || '| param1: ' || :param1;

END;
```

and to read its response i have the following java code

```
 if (connection != null) {
              try {
           String Stm = "CALL \"PRATIK\".\"PRC_test3_2\"("+param1+",'"+param2+"',"+outparams1+")";

                 System.out.println("Connection to HANA successful!");
                 java.sql.Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                 java.sql.ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(Stm);
                 resultSet.next();

                 String res1 = resultSet.getString(1);
                 System.out.println("This is the result of the query -- "+res1);
                 //System.out.println("METADATA -- "+resultSet.getMetaData());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.err.println("Query failed!");
               System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
```

when i execute this code it give me an error that the output is not of type resultSet. following is the stack trace.

> Query failed!
>       [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6504e3b2
>       com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: SQL statement does not generate a result set.
>           at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:197)
>           at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:26)
>           at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB._executeQuery(StatementSapDB.java:1355)
>           at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.executeQuery(StatementSapDB.java:162)
>           at com.saphana.tibco.Procedure.main(Procedure.java:33)

Is there a way of reading string output from PL/SQl from java with out changing the sql proc to give result in sql return format as show below

```
SELECT
         :param1 as "outParam1"
           FROM Dummy;
```

Comment: do you mind including the stacktrace details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Pratik please go through below link 
We need to use callableStatement, as resulset will not work

https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

Answer (score 0):

I have only worked with H2Db with java not with the PL/SQL but I think the Java thing is gonna be the same. The way I did it was like you need a prepare statement and then a result set to execute the query. You don't need `boolean stmt`, you can directly prepare a statement execute the query and assign it to result set. Below is a snippet. Let me know if this solution works or not.

```
    if (connection != null) {
              try {
                 String Stm = "CALL \"PRATIK\".\"PRC_test3_2\"("+param1+",'"+param2+"',"+outparams1+")";
                 System.out.println("Connection to HANA successful!");
                 PreparedStatement process = connection.prepareStatement(Stm).;
                 java.sql.ResultSet resultSet = process.executeQuery(Stm);
                 if(resultSet.next()){
                     while(resultSet.next()){
                         String res1 = resultSet.getString("name");
                         System.out.println("This is the result of the query -- "+res1);
                     }
                  }
                 //System.out.println("METADATA -- "+resultSet.getMetaData());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.err.println("Query failed!");
               System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
```

**NOTE : When you are trying to get the value, you can pass the column name. For e.g., if you are trying to get the name let's say your column name is "name", you need to pass getString("name")**